# How to transver the pressure applied on Normal vector of traigular element to its nodes in FEM?

Tags: finite-element-analysis

I have a triangular element with **A,B,C** as Vertices. I have applied a pressure **P** on the normal **N** of the triangular surface. now i Need to calculate the force acting on the nodes of the triangular element. Its done in an FEM process. Please explain me how to do it with mathematical formulas. let the bulk data of triangle be:

```
 A(1000,20,30);B(1200,25,30);C(1000,20,35) 
and normal calculated by me N(25,-1000,0) 
and applied pressure 1bar in direction of normal N 
and i Need to calculate force acting on A,B,C
```

Please just let me know to do as a mathematical way.Thank you for your effort

Comment: this seems off topic here to me (not a programming quesiton). I'd suggest you try here : http://imechanica.org/forum/109. That said I kind of doubt simply equally distributing the force to the nodes is formally correct unless the triangle is equilateral.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of type of your element (namely, CST or DKT or ...), there are several approaches for converting the uniform body load into nodal loads for surface or volume elements. One of these approaches is 'Lumped' which means total force does distribute equally between your nodes. For your case, I suggest you to do these steps to find answer based on Lumped approach:

1. Find your triangle area (result is a scalar number)
2. Multiply it with your pressure (result is a scalar number)
3. Find 'Unit Vector' of your N (result is a vector)
4. Multiply the result from step 2 with result from step 3, and that is the total force applying on your element (result is a vector)
5. Result from step 4 is equally distribute between nodes, which mean each node will have 1/3 of it. (answer is a vector)

Comment: Hey i also did the same way, but instead of calculating area, i just did element wise product of pressure scalar value on to the normal vector and found the components similarly. any ways thanks for answering